# Quickfixj :i need to know what is the limitations and the problems for QuickFixJ

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

i need to know what is the limitations and the problems for QuickFixJ since i want to start development on it and i want to know if there's any problems with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the jira page for [QuickfixJ](http://www.quickfixj.org/jira/browse/QFJ). You can see the list of bugs other people have discovered in QuickfixJ. But problems which are going to affect you depends on what you are doing with the library. But you do have the source code with you, so you can tweak as you want. If you want a better FIX engine, you have to get a commercial one rather than an open source one.

Comment: do you suggest any commercial  better than QuickFixJ ??!!

Comment: @rifai15 - Hell no !! I was suggesting if you have money to spare then do so. Else you can modify the Quickfix library as such to your liking.